# How to find the url of a media library image field in a preprocess function?

Tags: theming, media

I have a preprocess function that I am using to grab one of 3 profile images.  Basically we're replacing a couple stand-alone image fields with a media library reference field.  The goal is to display the media library image if it is populated at a particular style (called '65x65') or fall back to other stand-alone legacy image fields if it is not populated.

I'm having a heck of a time building the media library image url.  I have tried quite a few things based on [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_image/issues/2856093) and [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2019-05-20/how-to-get-image-file-uri-from-media) and others.  The image field on the image media type is called field_media_image (screenshot)[image: media image setup].  I'm not sure if it's useful to post my half-baked code attempts so I will leave the parts that I know are working.

```
foreach ($block->field_block_contributors->referencedEntities() as $contributor) {
    # prefer the media library reference profile image if it exists

    if (!$contributor->field_profile_image->isEmpty()) { # check if there is a media library profile image

      $my_profile_image = $contributor->get('field_profile_image')->referencedEntities(); # seems to load this field ok
      if (!empty($my_profile_image)) {
      // kint($my_profile_image);
      # load a media library image using the '65x65' image style
      // $styled_image_url = ??????


      }
    } elseif (!$contributor->field_user_image->isEmpty()) { # or fall back to one of two legacy image fields.  This part works
      $styled_image_url = ImageStyle::load('65x65')->buildUrl($contributor->field_user_image->entity->getFileUri());
    } elseif (!$contributor->field_speaker_image->isEmpty()) {
      $styled_image_url = ImageStyle::load('65x65')->buildUrl($contributor->field_speaker_image->entity->getFileUri());
    } else {
      $styled_image_url = '';
    }
    $variables['profiles'][] = [
      'title' => $contributor->field_user_title->value,
      'link' => "/user/" . $contributor->uid->value,
      'image' => ['src' => $styled_image_url, 'attributes' => $contributor->field_user_image->value],
      'name' => $contributor->field_user_first_name->value . " " . $contributor->field_user_last_name->value,
    ];
  }
```

PS. Bonus beer for anyone who knows off the top of their heads how I can link to the user's name instead of their user id # ( the line    'link' => "/user/" . $contributor->uid->value, )
Thanks!!!

Comment: What is field_profile_image? Is this the entity reference to the media entity? Then you could go the same as with the other fields by $my_profile_image->field_media_image. What do you mean about "if it is populated at a particular style"? If the image and style exists Drupal "populates" it for you if you do it the right way. I would recommend you to get a little more in touch with Drupal rendering and display view modes. This code seems to go away (probably unnecessarily) from "Drupal patterns".

Comment: To answer the Bonus question: [To get a URL string](https://api.drupal.org/comment/63759#comment-63759)

Comment: Yes, field_profile_image is an entity reference field from the *user* to the media library image.  So field_profile_image is a custom field for the user.  (see screenshot for user fields here https://i.imgur.com/RkqrMAA.png ).  Sorry I did not explain that well at all.  I'm simply trying to find the url to the referenced image and display it at the existing "65x65" display mode.  Yes I am familiar with drupal rendering and display modes and believe I am on the right track here.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Oh, so on the bonus question just 'link' => $contributor->toUrl()->toString(), nice one!!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but I was able to pull it off with...

```
      if (!$contributor->field_profile_image->isEmpty()) { # check if there is a media library profile image

      $my_image = $contributor->get('field_profile_image')->getValue()[0]['target_id']; # Find ID of media library image
      $media_entity_load = Media::load($my_image); // Loading media entity.
      $uri = $media_entity_load->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri(); // It is for image media.
      $styled_image_url = ImageStyle::load('65x65')->buildUrl($uri); // Here you will get URL of uploaded image.
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little module I found helpful to get the media entity image values.

**custom_helper_services/custom_helper_services.info.yml:**

```
name: 'Custom Helper Services'
type: module
description: 'Provides useful services for working with themes.'
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
package: 'Custom'
```

**custom_helper_services/custom_helper_services.module:**

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains custom_helper_services.module.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function custom_helper_services_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    // Main module help for the custom_helper_services module.
    case 'help.page.custom_helper_services':
      $output = '';
      $output .= '<h3>' . t('About') . '</h3>';
      $output .= '<p>' . t('Provides helpful service functions.') . '</p>';
      return $output;

    default:
  }
}
```

**custom_helper_services/custom_helper_services.services.yml:**

```
services:
  chs:
    class: Drupal\custom_helper_services\Services\CustomHelperServices
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager','@current_route_match','@entity.repository']
```

**custom_helper_services/src/Services/CustomHelperServices.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_helper_services\Services;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class CustomHelperServices.
 *
 * Provides helper services to be used in modules and themes.
 */
class CustomHelperServices {

  /**
   * Entity Type Manager.
   *
   * @var Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * Route Match Interface.
   *
   * @var Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface
   */
  protected $routeMatch;

  /**
   * Entity Repository Interface.
   *
   * @var Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepositoryInterface
   */
  protected $entityRepository;

  /**
   * CustomHelperServices constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager
   *   Entity Type Manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $routeMatch
   *   The Route Match Interface.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepositoryInterface $entityRepository
   *   The Entity Repository Interface.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager, RouteMatchInterface $routeMatch, EntityRepositoryInterface $entityRepository) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entityTypeManager;
    $this->routeMatch = $routeMatch;
    $this->entityRepository = $entityRepository;
  }

  /**
   * Build our media style path service.
   */
  public function getMediaFieldImage($mediaField = NULL, $imageStyle = NULL) {

    if ($mediaField && $mediaField->entity) {

      // Get image.
      $mediaImage = $mediaField->entity
        ->get('field_media_image');

      // Get image attributes.
      $alt = $mediaImage->alt;
      $width = $mediaImage->width;
      $height = $mediaImage->height;
      $title = $mediaImage->title;

      // Get image entity.
      $mediaImageEntity = $mediaImage->entity;

      // Get image mime type.
      $mediaImageMimeType = $mediaImageEntity->getMimeType();

      // Get image file URI.
      $mediaImageEntityUri = $mediaImageEntity->getFileUri();

      // Set image URL.
      $url = file_create_url($mediaImageEntityUri);

      // Set image style URL.
      if ($imageStyle && $mediaImageMimeType !== "image/svg+xml") {
        $url = $this->entityTypeManager
          ->getStorage('image_style')
          ->load($imageStyle)
          ->buildUrl($mediaImageEntityUri);
      }

      return [
        'url' => $url,
        'alt' => $alt,
        'width' => $width,
        'height' => $height,
        'mimeType' => $mediaImageMimeType,
        'title' => $title,
      ];
    }

    return NULL;
  }

}
```

Then in preprocess node, for example, you can call:

```
$variables['myVariable'] = \Drupal::service('chs')->getMediaFieldImage($node->get("field_name"), "image_style");
// Just need to pass the media field name. The image style is optional.
```

Then in a Twig template you can access as:

```
{{ myVariable.url }}
{{ myVariable.alt }}
{{ myVariable.width }}
{{ myVariable.height }}
{{ myVariable.mimeType }}
{{ myVariable.title }}
```

I've stripped down this code to show just the media entity image get, so let me know if there are issues and I can update if needed.

---

A shorter version (using preprocess_node()):

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->hasField('field_name') && $node->get('field_name')->entity) {
    $imageURI = $node->field_name->entity->getFileUri();
    $variables['myVariable'] = ImageStyle::load('image_style')->buildUrl($imageURI);
  }
}
```